# How to align a TextView to the right with LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout

I have two textView objects that I am using to display the result of the calculations in my app.  They are showing up to the right of the TextView so I wanted to know if there is a way through the xml file to position the TextView to the right.  This is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.jtryon.rectanglecalc.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/width_string"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/width_edit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"      
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" > 

        <requestFocus />
        </EditText>       

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >  

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/height_string"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" /> 

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/height_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />     

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:text="@string/area_string" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/area_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/perim_string"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/perim_string" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/perim_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>    

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: How it should look]

Comment: Could you be a little more clear? Maybe an image of what you have/want? I know that you want one of these many `TextView`s to the right of something...

Comment: You have more control with Constraint Layouts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure your view matches the parent, then add the gravity of its content to the right:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/width_string" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helped ;)

Comment: No, see my comment on the other post. This won't work

Comment: It will, the TextView will occupy the rest of the width, and the text inside it will shift to the right.

Comment: The `TextView` will occupy the entire width and `gravity` should be used to move the text instead of `layout_gravity`. Anyway, I'm not sure that is what the OP wants.

Comment: sorry, my bad, it's `gravity`

Comment: I did try to use android:gravity="right" but it did not shift the TextView and the value to the right. I will post a screenshot.

Comment: Can you edit the your xml file with the new code you used with `gravity="right"` and also tell de `id` of which TextView you want to align right?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:gravity="end"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_call_white"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please check that Linear Layout has an attribute named GRAVITY and inner control(ImageView) has an attribute named LAYOUT_GRAVITY 
both are different

Answer (score 2):

Just add the line

```
android:gravity="right"
```

to the textview you want aligned left.

Comment: And also if what i have in mind is what you want,change the main layout orientation from vertical to horizontal

Comment: `gravity` left and right won't do any good in a horizontal `LinearLayout`

Comment: @codeMagic am thinking he wants the text in the textview aligned left,thats why

Comment: I understand. My original comment still stands. Just like top and bottom do nothing with a vertically oriented `LinearLayout`

Comment: @codeMagic in that case changing orientation to horizontal and gravity to left will do.I stand to be corrected though.

Comment: No, that's what you are proposing but it won't do anything. The child linear layouts are already horizontal. Anyway, hard to say what the OP wants without an image

Comment: I got it working using layout_gravity="right" and layout_weight="1" for the textview.  I was wondering though if gravity is dependent on weight and if they work one without the other.

Comment: Just to clarify, I wanted the text to the right and not left.

Comment: @JimT you should have clarified that in the beginning. This was the right answer then. so +1 here.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just change the order of the elements inside the LinearLayout.  Make sure the EditText field is first and then the TextView field.  Easy.